# Is there a faster way than applying 'ddply' to aggregate columns by groups with a large dataset?

Tags: r

## Purpose

I am trying to check whether a pair of values in two columns appear in the previous event, and aggregate the dummy variables by groups.

Specifically, I have each event id (i.e., oid) and dyad-level observations associated with each event: agent (i.e., aid), partner (i.e., pid). The events are sorted by time when the event occurs (i.e., o4.in).

(1)I made a dummy variable indicating if a pair of agent and partner appear together in the previous event.

(2) Also, I used ddply to aggregate the dummy variable by groups, as specified in the below example.

**I find that ddply and lag functions take so much time with a large dataset, and I am wondering if there is a faster way to achieved these tasks.**

## Dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
  library(tibble)
  
  rename <- dplyr::rename
  select <- dplyr::select
  
  set.seed(10001)
  cases <- sample(1:5, 1000, replace=T)
  
  set.seed(10002)
  agent <- sample(1:20, 1000, replace=T)
  
  set.seed(10003)
  partner <- sample(1:20, 1000, replace=T)
    
  set.seed(123)
  n <- 1000  # no of random datetimes needed
  minDate <- as.POSIXct("1999/01/01")
  maxDate <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01")
  
  epoch <- "1970-01-01"
  timestamps <- 
    as.POSIXct(pmax(runif(n, minDate, maxDate), runif(n, minDate, maxDate)), origin = epoch)
  
  df <-
    data.frame(cases, agent, partner, timestamps) %>% 
    rename(
      aid = agent,
      pid = partner,
      oid = cases,
      o4.in = timestamps
    ) %>% 
    filter(aid != pid)
```

## Current Methods

```
 # creating dummy variable
  d <- 
    df %>% 
    arrange(o4.in) %>% 
    group_by(aid) %>% 
    mutate(
      oid.lag.a = lag(oid)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    group_by(pid)  %>% 
    mutate(
      oid.lag.p = lag(oid)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(
      j2.consecutive = ifelse(oid.lag.a == oid.lag.p, 1, 0),
      j2.consecutive = ifelse(is.na(j2.consecutive), 0, j2.consecutive)
    ) %>% 
    select(-oid.lag.a, -oid.lag.p)
    
 # aggregating the dummy variable by groups
  t <- 
    d %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    ddply(c('oid', 'aid'), function(i){
      i %>%
        mutate(aj1.consecutive = (sum(j2.consecutive) - j2.consecutive)/(n()-1))
    } , .progress = 'text') %>%
    arrange(oid, pid) %>% 
    ddply(c('oid', 'pid'), function(i){ 
      i %>% 
        mutate(apj1.consecutive = (sum(j2.consecutive) - j2.consecutive)/(n()-1))
    } , .progress = 'text')
```

## Update for Future Readers

Task (1) is achieved by the answer by @akrun below.
Task (2) solution is answered by @akrun in a separate post: [A faster way than applying 'ddply' to aggregate a variable by a function by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169787/a-faster-way-than-applying-ddply-to-aggregate-a-variable-by-a-function-by-grou/68169873#68169873)

Special thanks to @akrun!!

Comment: Hi Akrun, good to see you again. Thanks for catching it, and I corrected the code!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, while `tidyverse` and `magrittr` are awesome for data exploration, they tend to be the slowest of R libraries. I would recommend switching to `data.table` if performance is an issue.

Comment: How big is your data.  with `n <- 100000` I am getting comparable speed in the dplyr modified/data.table - but data.table have an edge.  It is still better than your dplyr code timings or way better than `plyr`

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thank you for your suggestion! I think Akrun provided the solution using data.table. :)

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you so much for your continuing help. I have 4 million observations, and I will try your data.table solution!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods to make it faster

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- copy(df)
df3 <- setDT(df2)[order(o4.in)]
df3[, oid.lag.a := shift(oid), by = aid
    ][, oid.lag.p := shift(oid), by = pid]
          
df3[, j2.consecutive := fcoalesce(+(oid.lag.a == oid.lag.p), 0L)]
```

---

Also, note that some things in the OP's code are unnecessary i.e. using `ifelse` to convert a logical to binary.  It can just be `as.integer` or coercion with `+`.  The second line again with `ifelse` can be removed as well with `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
    arrange(o4.in) %>% 
    group_by(aid) %>% 
    mutate(
      oid.lag.a = lag(oid)
    ) %>%     
    group_by(pid)  %>% 
    mutate(
      oid.lag.p = lag(oid)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(j2.consecutive = coalesce(+(oid.lag.a == oid.lag.p), 0))
```

-checking the output from `dplyr/data.table`

```
all(out$j2.consecutive == df3$j2.consecutive )
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi @akrun ! Thanks a lot for providing me with the answer for the first question. Do you also know how I can achieve the second set of task - making table t in the example I made?  Using `ddply` in aggregating the dummy variable into some values by groups takes so long time for my 4 million obs dataset. My Rstudio actually keep being terminated. :( I appreciate it for your help.

Comment: @J.K.  Generally, it is better to post with a single question per post as I didn't notice the second case

Comment: to @akrun ,  I am pretty new to this community, and my apologies to make it confusing. I will post it again! :)

Comment: @J.K.  It is okay.  No need to feel sorry about it.  It is just that people only look for single questions.  With multiple questions, the possibility of getting solution are decreased as people  look for solving questions that takes less time to solve

Comment: To @akrun It is a very good tip!! Thank you!!

Comment: By the way @akrun , the codes for the first question work perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @J.K. Can you update your post with the benchmarks based on dplyr/plyr and data.table so that future readers would  benefit.  thanks

Comment: could you clarify it little bit more? do you mean that I can update the original post with several ways of doing the tasks using  1. dplyr/plyr, 2. data.table incorporating your answers including your answer in another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169787/a-faster-way-than-applying-ddply-to-aggregate-a-variable-by-a-function-by-grou/68169873#68169873   ?

Comment: @J.K. I posted a solution in your new post.  It actually motivated me to try and add a new solution.  I would keep the new post as it is a separate question which is kind of followup with this question

Comment: Sounds great! I will update this post so that the future reader can find the solution to the second task by visiting the new post. @akrun I appreciate it for teaching me how to behave in this community.