# A faster way than applying 'ddply' to aggregate a variable by a function by groups

Tags: r

## Purpose

I have event id (i.e., `oid`) and dyad-level observations associated with each event: agent (i.e., `aid`), partner (i.e., `pid`). The events are sorted by time when the event occurs (i.e., `o4.in`). Also, I have a variable to indicate whether a pair of values in two columns appear in the previous event (i.e., `j2.consecutive`).

I used `ddply` to aggregate the dummy variable by groups, as specified in the below example (e.g., `t2` to create `aj1.consecutive` and `apj1.consecutive`). However, with 4m observations, the code takes too much time and Rstudio is terminated often while running the code.

Is there a faster & compact way to achieve the same task other than applying `ddply`?

## Dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
  library(tibble)
  library(data.table)
  
  rename <- dplyr::rename
  select <- dplyr::select
  
  set.seed(10001)
  cases <- sample(1:5, 1000, replace=T)
  
  set.seed(10002)
  agent <- sample(1:20, 1000, replace=T)
  
  set.seed(10003)
  partner <- sample(1:20, 1000, replace=T)
    
  set.seed(123)
  n <- 1000  # no of random datetimes needed
  minDate <- as.POSIXct("1999/01/01")
  maxDate <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01")
  
  epoch <- "1970-01-01"
  timestamps <- 
    as.POSIXct(pmax(runif(n, minDate, maxDate), runif(n, minDate, maxDate)), origin = epoch)
  
  df <-
    data.frame(cases, agent, partner, timestamps) %>% 
    rename(
      aid = agent,
      pid = partner,
      oid = cases,
      o4.in = timestamps
    ) %>% 
    filter(aid != pid) %>%
    arrange(o4.in) 

  t <- setDT(df)[order(o4.in)]
  t[, oid.lag.a := shift(oid), by = aid
  ][, oid.lag.p := shift(oid), by = pid]
  
  t <- 
    t[, j2.consecutive := fcoalesce(+(oid.lag.a == oid.lag.p), 0L)] %>% 
    arrange(aid, o4.in)
```

## Current Method

```
 # aggregating the dummy variable by groups
 t2 <-
t %>%
ungroup %>%
ddply(c('oid', 'aid'), function(i){
  i %>%
    mutate(aj1.consecutive = (sum(j2.consecutive) - j2.consecutive)/(n()-1))
} , .progress = 'text') %>%
arrange(oid, pid) %>%
ddply(c('oid', 'pid'), function(i){
  i %>%
    mutate(apj1.consecutive = (sum(j2.consecutive) - j2.consecutive)/(n()-1))
} , .progress = 'text') %>%
arrange(aid, o4.in)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient `data.table` option would be with `:=` and `set` functions.  According to `?':='`

> set is a low-overhead loop-able version of :=. It is particularly useful for repetitively updating rows of certain columns by reference (using a for-loop).

Also, based on `?setorder`

> setorder (and setorderv) reorders the rows of a data.table based on the columns (and column order) provided. It reorders the table by reference and is therefore very memory efficient.

Below code assigns (`:=`) by reference grouped by 'oid', 'aid' or 'oid', 'pid' and does the order with `setorder` thus making it more efficient.  The `copy` was made on the original object so that it won't get changed while doing the assignment

```
library(data.table)
t3 <- copy(t)

t3[, aj1.consecutive :=  (sum(j2.consecutive) - 
            j2.consecutive)/(.N-1), .(oid, aid)]
setorder(t3, oid, pid)
t3[, apj1.consecutive := (sum(j2.consecutive) - 
            j2.consecutive)/(.N-1), .(oid, pid)]
setorder(t3, aid, o4.in)
```

-checking with OP's output

```
all.equal(t2, t3, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: To @akrun , It achieved the task, and you motivated me to study `data.table` thoroughly. Do you have any recommended materials to study it? I understand you are busy, so it is okay if you do not answer it. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @J.K. I would check the [`data.table-vignette`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) which would give more uptodate info

Comment: I will totally go for it. Many thanks!! @akrun